# Difference between PrintWriter.printf and PrintWriter.format methods

Tags: java

Is there any difference between the Java `PrintWriter` methods `printf` and `format`?

The doc says `printf` is a convenience method but if it behaves exactly as `format`, so I don't understand what's convenient about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A convenience method is as the name implies -- it exists just for the sake of convenience, not necessarily for function.

One common case where convenience methods exist is for methods which have multiple arguments, but some arguments are used in a particular manner. Many times, the same method will be overloaded with different arguments.

Take the following code:

```
public void myMethod(int value, boolean hasImportance) {
    // do something.
}

public void myMethod(int value) {
    myMethod(value, true);
}
```

In the above example, the `myMethod(int)` method can be thought of as a convenience method for `myMethod(int, boolean)`, as it provides a default argument for one of its parameters.

In the case of [`PrintWriter.printf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), it is basically invoking [`PrintWriter.format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), but just provides an alternate way of invoking the `format` method.

Probably the justification behind the creation of the `printf` method as a convenience method is because the `printf` method's naming conveys the meaning that one is trying to output with formatting rather than just `format`, which doesn't convey the intent that one is trying to perform a output with formatting.

Comment: I'd say its convenience lies in the fact that now there is a method called printf() -- parametrized as the c function -- for all objects having to do with printing strinigs. So you don't have to remember those proprietary print method names as before, just use printf.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://kickjava.com/src/java/io/PrintWriter.java.htm), they are the same

```
 /**
  ...
  * <p> An invocation of this method of the form <tt>out.printf(format,
  * args)</tt> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
  *
  * <pre>
  * out.format(format, args) </pre>
  ...
 */
 public PrintWriter printf(String  format, Object ... args) {
    return format(format, args);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here convenience can be interpreted of in two ways.

First way

Developers generally are more acquainted with the "printf" function. Hence it is used often.

Second way

If any changes are to be made to printf and format (in case of any bugs or functionality),

one function can be used to retain the old functionality and the other can be easily modified.